# Generate ERD from JavaScript

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, angular, swagger

I'm building an Angular Universal application using TypeORM + MySQL. Is there any way in JavaScript to programmatically create an ERD from my TypeORM specification?

I see some related things but nothing exactly what I want:

1. [rails-erd](https://github.com/voormedia/rails-erd) can do what I want for Rails apps.
2. [Mermaid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mermaid) can make the diagram I want from markup, but not from reading the same Angular models.
3. [MySQL Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) can make the ERD after TypeORM has setup the database, but this is not an all-JS solution.
4. [ember-erd](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-erd) does what I want for Ember apps.

TypeScript has some kind of Swagger integration I think, so maybe there is some way to generate the ERD from that? Or is there a way to have MySQL automatically generate the ERD without installing Workbench, perhaps via a Node module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement it with cola.js on the basis of D3JS http://ialab.it.monash.edu/webcola/ It is not the ideal solution but it can be used to emulate ERD.